# Docker pull ERROR HTTP 206 from byte range request

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry, docker-pull

I'm trying to run **docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019**  on windows10 machine

ERROR: expected HTTP 206 from byte range request